# When you use "just say no" to a "rent" do others player still need to pay?

Tags: monopoly-deal

When player A uses two colored rent. And player B uses "just say no".

Does player C still needs to pay to player A?

Comment: What do either of those methods mean?

Comment: @JoeW I think you believe this is a Monopoly question but it actually is a Monopoly Deal question as the tag suggests. More info on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_Deal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording on the "Just Say No" card says "Use any time when an action card is played against you. Play in the center to use." Which doesn't even tell you what the card *does*. So that's no help.

The rules themselves say "Use this card at any time to cancel the effect when another player plays any Action card against you. If that player has another Just Say No card, they can use it to cancel yours ... sorry! Can also be banked as money." Ok, so it "cancels the effect". But is that effect the whole card, or just the bit where you have to pay rent? Not clear at all.

The official website, as far as I can tell, doesn't exist. However, there is what appears to be a fairly official-looking fan-built site at http://www.monopolydealrules.com that has a FAQ, which includes [an entire section on "Just Say No"](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=justsayno). Question number 7 seems relevant:

> **7. Does a Just Say No cancel the action against you or everyone? If I Just Say No someone's two color rent card do I only get out of paying rent or does everyone?**
>
> This is something that can be played either way but most people play that it only no's the action for you. So in a scenario where someone charges everyone two million using a It's My Birthday card and you lay a Just Say No, only you would not have to pay.

So the most official source available that actually answers the question is not actually official at all, and doesn't actually answer the question one way or the other (although it does make a suggestion as to which ruling to pick). Short of playing the Ubisoft version and seeing how the cards are implemented in it, I don't think there is an answer to have.

Comment: I see, we will probably used the most used rules
and thanks for sharing that site

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know the game but what I can see from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_Deal) the card only collects rent from one player any way:

> Multi-colored rent cards: The function of this kind of cards is collect rent of any one of the colors of your properties **from one rival**.

Comment: That's true of the multi-coloured rent card (the one that collects on any colour of property), but there are also rent cards that let you choose one of two specific colours, and they collect from all other players. I will need to check my cards at home to see the specific wording of the cards.

Comment: @ConMan is right
i meant normal/double colored rent cards not multi/all colored ones

from the same wiki:

Rent cards: You can collect rent of either one set of your properties from **all rivals**.